# CVXPY set Z to 1 if B is positive

Tags: python, cvxpy

So here's the problem. I have this variable Z which follows the following rule:

[image: if loan j has a positive balance at time t Z = 1, otherwise Z = 0]

I'm guessing Z should be defined as so:

```
Z = cvxpy.Variable(shape=shape_j_t, name="Z", boolean=True)
```

So Z is constrained(?) to the balance "B". How do I inform the solver that Z should be 1 if B is positive and 0 otherwise? Especially given that B itself is composed of other `cvxpy.Variables`.

Answer (score 2):

The general approach, assuming a-priori knowledge about *bounds* (which are needed in general) on `B` looks like:

```
b <= UB * z
b >= LB * z
z in {0, 1}
```

which describes:

```
z = 0 <-> b = 0
z = 1 <-> LB <= b <= UB
```

But this is just something general and these things usually are designed having the full model in mind. Here we don't know what you are doing exactly. Sometimes we don't need equivalence but just implication (e.g. ignore the LB-constraint...)

Maybe it's not trivial to *define the notion of positive balance* as you only got *inequalities* and using `LB=0` would express *non-negativity*, but not *strict positiveness*. For the latter, some *a-priori* definition of some *epsilon* (e.g. `0.001`) would be needed.